# Get Spring Form Action Attribute For Angular js

Tags: angularjs, spring, jsp, cas

I'm trying to customize Jasig's CAS 4.0.0 to a new view using Angular 1.4. But i have a problem on this time, here i can't use the angular tags on the current `<form:form>` tag, and also i have no idea to extract the bean that,it uses to define the `action=cas/login?...` part. Here's what it uses:

The viewLogin.jsp that uses the form:

```
<form:form method="post" id="fm1" modelAttribute="${commandName}"htmlEscape="true" cssClass="form-validate mb-lg" novalidate="">
```

I again changed from commandName to modelAttribute, because i saw a question saying it was outdated... But i still haven't any idea how to extract the information which i need from that form. Apparently, that's just a name to instantiate a bean that is resolved by spring automatically. But how can i access that information outside of the JSP attribute? Also I want to make the validation from Angular to complete it, but since that i cannot extract the URL that CAS generates, I can't make it "totally works".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of submitting the form directly to server, you can give an angular attribute in form, `onSubmit=formSubmit()`, which will call a function. This way you can intercept the form submission and can do custom validation. Once the data is validated, you can do a post to server.

Comment: @redflar3 but that's not really good, as i can't use the angular tags on the JSP tags. I want to substitute the JSP for the normal HTML exactly to be able to do that, but i can't because of the way that it's generated automatically by CAS. I want to know what to do to allow for "the angular way", as in, not using any JSP at all (eventually, i would like to substitute all the jsp's on CAS for normal HTML using angular and then github it to make someone's life easier).

Comment: The point of angular is to build a thick client where angular manages the pages. In this model, you dont have to request for page refresh every time the view needs a change. Where as if you let the JSP submit the form, it will result in a view change, which negates the point of having angular. The way we handle form submissions when using angular is by letting angular take care of the form submission, angular then do a post to the server, angular will receive the response from server and display updated values in view. This is tricky to achieve with JSP as its a think client kind of model.

Comment: Yes, and that's exactly what i want to do! I want to kill the JSP of the page and use an angular-way, with two way data binding, instant validation and all of it's magic. I dunno if i haven't made myself clear enough, but i want to know how(if it's possible) to substitute that JSP part for a plain HTML. In the case, i'd need to mantain the JSP because of CAS/Spring that manages the bean that it calls. In my application, i also have another field that i need to concatenate with the username field, so i need to do that before doing the POST anyways. That's why the angular.

Comment: In that case its a broad subject, can you please do some research online on migrating from JSP to angular...